# What is the correct regular expression syntax to keep + and . when removing non-matching characters from a string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to remove Non-ASCII characters but keeping any `['_','-','+', '.']` from a string.

The following works for all but `['+', '.']`

```
import re
text = 'ValidCharactersForPassword123._-+.AndRemoveNonAscii-áéíóú'
re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9_-]+','',text)
```

which returns 'ValidCharactersForPassword123_-AndRemoveNonAscii-' where
`['+', '.']` have been removed which is correct.

I'm looking to get a result like `'ValidCharactersForPassword123_-+.AndRemoveNonAscii-`

I've tried escaping the + and . but what I've tried fails.

```
re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9_-\+]+','',text)
re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9_-\\+]+','',text)
re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9_-\\\+]+','',text)
```

returned errors like

```
error: bad character range _-\\ at position 11
```

What is the correct syntax to keep + and . when removing non-matching characters from a string?

Comment: The `-` is the problem, it must go at the beginning of the character class.

Comment: Or at the end!!!

Comment: You're removing more than the non-ASCII characters. ASCII includes ``!" #$%&'()*,/:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~`` as well as a bunch of non-printing characters. I also don't expect it is necessary to remove these for password security; let people use these characters in their passwords if they want.

Comment: I prefer letting any characters in a password ... the app I'm working with does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure that you add all characters to your negative class which you want to spare from removal.  Note that the only character in your interest which would need to be escaped inside the class is `-`.  But, as you are already doing, we can just move it to the end of the class to avoid having to escape it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
text = 'ValidCharactersForPassword123._-+.AndRemoveNonAscii-áéíóú'
output = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9_+.-]+','',text)
print(output)

ValidCharactersForPassword123._-+.AndRemoveNonAscii-
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it like this**

When you use `-` at `end` or `start` of character class you don't need to escape it else you need to escape it

```
[^A-Za-z0-9_+.-]+
```

Code

```
import re
text = 'ValidCharactersForPassword123._-+.AndRemoveNonAscii-áéíóú'
re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9_+.-]+','',text)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VJGMVJ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't put the escaped `+` or `.` *(or any other re characters)* just after the `-` as this can cause problems:

```
In [3]: import re
   ...: text = 'ValidCharactersForPassword123._-+.AndRemoveNonAscii-áéíóú'
   ...: re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9\+\._-]+','',text)
Out[3]: 'ValidCharactersForPassword123._-+.AndRemoveNonAscii-'
```

This is because your original code was interpreting `"[...._-\+]"` as any character in the range `_` to `+`.

You can also escape the `-` as in:

```
In [1]: import re
   ...: text = 'ValidCharactersForPassword123._-+.AndRemoveNonAscii-áéíóú'
   ...: re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9\._\-\+]+','',text)
Out[1]: 'ValidCharactersForPassword123._-+.AndRemoveNonAscii-'
```